# Trigger to prevent duplicate records to insert

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

I am trying to write a trigger to prevent duplicate records to enter in my custom object.
I know we can do with one list and then write SOQL . I am trying to do with Ola map but missing some where. here is the code

public class TeacherTriggerHandler {

```
Public static void duplicate(List<Teacher__c> lstteach, Map<id,Teacher__c> oldmap)
{
    list<Teacher__c> newteach = oldmap.values();
    for(Teacher__c tc : lstteach )
    {
          if(newteach.contains(tc.Name))
        {
           tc.AddError('duplicate record found');
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Don't, you're doing it wrong.

Writing a trigger for this is a horrible task:

- handle duplicates in the list being inserted
- check for existing records in database (and pray the user can see them, sharing may hide problems from non-admin)
- handle updates that change the name
- handle sneaky tester creating teacher1, deleting it, creating teacher2 with same Name, restoring the 1 from recycle bin

Do it properly, use the tools SF gives you.

Define duplicate rules and "block" action that stops the save.

Or old school solution is to have a helper text field, mark it as unique and keep your trigger simple - "before insert, before update" copy value from Name to that field. If it crashes - it crashes :) (and for that you don't need a trigger, "early flow" will be enough)

Comment: Note that Duplicate Rules aren't supported for all standard objects

Comment: @cropredy `Teacher__c` suggests it's not a problem in OP's case

Comment: agreed; more of a comment for others reaching this question.